# Customize NavigationDrawer with RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a picture on top of my `NavigationDrawer` and below a `ListView` which contains the navigation items. So i set up a `LinearLayout` for the `NavigationDrawer` which contains an `ImageView` and the `ListView`. Unfortunately it doesnt work and i get the error:

```
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pymdev.pym_app/com.example.pymdev.pym_app.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3439)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3310)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.addView(DrawerLayout.java:1730)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3286)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.pymdev.pym_app.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:51)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
10-22 16:39:00.609 6555-6555/com.example.pymdev.pym_app E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.pymdev.pym_app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:id="@+id/navDrawerLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pym_cooler_drawer"/>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerListView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/dark_divider" android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_selection"
        tools:context="com.example.pymdev.pym_app.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My activity_menu.xml:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pymdev.pym_app.MenuActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.pymdev.pym_app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawerFragment class:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    /* For top pic we need a linear layout wrapper */

    private LinearLayout mDrawerLinearLayout;

    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* Inflate the whole Linear Layout for the drawer */
        mDrawerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
         /* Find the encapsulated listView */
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) mDrawerLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerListView);
        /*
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        */

        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });


        //Use Custom Adapter instead:
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new CustomNavAdapter(
                NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(),
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.section_titles),
                new Integer[]{
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                }));

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    /* Custom array adapter tu support Images and Pictures combined */
    public class CustomNavAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Activity _context;
        private final String[] _text;
        private final Integer[] _imageId;

        public CustomNavAdapter(Activity context, String[] text, Integer[] imageId) {
            super(context, R.layout.navigation_drawer_textview, text);
            this._context = context;
            this._text = text;
            this._imageId = imageId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_textview, null, true);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            txtTitle.setText(_text[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(_imageId[position]);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            int selectedPosition = sharedPreferences.getInt("SELECTED_POSITION_KEY", -1);
            /*
            if (selectedPosition == position) {
                reviewImageView.setImageResource(yourSelectedImageResource);
            }
            */
            return rowView;
        }



    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout) {
            /* Logout from facebook */
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            /* Switch back to login screen */
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Can you please help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this, but since the new design support library, there is an easier way to implement a navigation drawer. Basically you implement a NavigationView with a menu xml file with the items in it (much like an overflow menu). So there's no need for a list adapter that inflates the items in a ListView. Also, you can create a separate layout for the header. [This](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/) is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Totally a shot in the dark, here, because there is a lot of Java code that I don't feel like looking through, but it looks like your fragment xml is misconfigured. Maybe you started with a ListView, then wrapped it in a LinearLayout? Try this instead.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.pymdev.pym_app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:id="@+id/navDrawerLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pym_cooler_drawer"/>

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerListView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/dark_divider" 
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_selection" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The xml seemed fine to me. However, if you're going to use this answer, you would probably want to set the LinearLayout's orientation to vertical. Placing the ImageView above the Listview, instead of next to eachother.

Comment: I was looking at the redeclaration of the `xmlns` in the ListView. I think that usually stays in the root element. Regarding the orientation, I was just respecting the OP's XML

Comment: The redeclaration is probably due to a copy paste, but I doubt that's the problem. As for the orientation, I missed that. So now I understand you were respecting his xml, makes sense. (For OP's purpose I would choose vertical though)

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually i got it working really nice using this tutorial:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

I followed everything exactly and now i also have a much cleaner project structure.